# How to add quotes in mysql query in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, mysql

I have a variable `$categoryName` which has value ABC/ABC (for example). I nedd to add quotes around this text "ABC/ABC". This is my PHP code:

```
public function getCategoryID($categoryName)
    {
        $row = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
        SELECT `id_category`
        FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_lang c
        WHERE c.`name` = ' . $categoryName);

        return isset($row['categoryName']);
    }
```

And the error from mysql.

```
SELECT `id_category`
        FROM ps_category_lang c
        WHERE c.`name` = ABC/ABC LIMIT 1
```

How to solve this problem ? Thanks for help.

Comment: If you mean quotes, then quote it. However, learn how to use prepared statements and you'll never have to worry about quoting your variables again. I'm not sure which mysql API you're using, so you'll have to check the docs for that.

Comment: Can you explain where you are stuck? You have not quoted anything, and this should be fairly easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the quotes in the string.

```
    $row = Db::getInstance()->getRow('
    SELECT `id_category`
    FROM ' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'category_lang c
    WHERE c.`name` = "' . $categoryName . '"');
```

As mentioned in the comments, it would be better if you used prepared statements to protect against SQL injection. If you can't do that, you should make sure to escape `$categoryName` properly.

See [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)